# Hole in knowledge in regard with TDD

Tags: c#, .net, tdd

I made a list (a so called "test list" in Test-Driven Development by Example) from which I will pick a test to implement.

So I start up Visual Studio, create a new solution, add a project for the unit tests, and then... I need to come up with a class in which I will put the test method for the test I picked of the list.

Here's where I get stuck. How do I know which class I need, how to name it and how to know if it is correct? Is this something that needed to be thought of beforehand?

Answer (score 3):

Have you read Kent Beck - TDD? Stop trying to work it all out in advance. Dive in, do something, make it work, what ever it is, then you will have a better idea of what it should be and you can change it.  The principal is this, think about what you want done before you think about how to do it.  Write a test that tests does something you want done, then implement a solution.  You will get it wrong first time, and second, and third, but the process will bring you closer to the actual solution, and by the time you are done you should  have valuable test suite and a set of loosely couple classes that get the job done.

EDIT IN REPONSE TO COMMENT

No, not a random name.  You need to perform a certain amount of design up front.  I often start by coming up with the key types that I think my solution will need.  I then start a test class (Say FooTest) in which I write a test for something that I want Foo to do. I use the process of writing the test to write the interface. Resharper is great for this as I can reference types and methods that do not yet exist and have Resharper create them:

```
[TestFixture]
public class FooTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Bar()
    {
        var foo = (IFoo)null;  //At this point I use Resharper to create IFoo interface

        Assert.IsTrue(foo.Bar()); //At this point I use Resharper to create bool IFoo.Bar();
    }
}
```

obviously the above will fail with a null ref ex., but I have a test and I have an interface with a method.  I can carry on following this process to model my solution until I reach a point when I am ready to develop a concrete implementation.  Following this process I focus on the interface and the interaction between types, not the implementation of those types.  Once I have built Foo I simply change the above to `var foo = new Foo();` and make all tests green.  This process also means I have an interface for every class which is essential when writing unit tests as I can easily mock dependencies using a dynamic mock lib, like [MOQ](http://code.google.com/p/moq/).

Comment: Yes, I read it. Are you suggesting I should just start with giving my class a random name and work it out from there? Because that's the problem I'm having, I'm having a list of tests, but no context.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this something that needed to be thought of beforehand?

Beforehand. That's the reason it called Test Driven Develop...
You have to design the workflow **before** starting to implement.

Comment: Because there seems to be two schools of thought it seems. One is to prepare like you would on any project get the business needs, collect user stories, etc. and work from there.

The other approach seems to be totally organic. You have nothing but the tests you want your program to do.

That second approach blocks me because it is hard to think of the context for the tests - I don't know for example how to name my test class. But, maybe this is as well something that needs to evolve. Maybe I should just give my test class some name, and this will change over time?

Comment: @GarthMarenghi. Actually I think you should have the tests after you designed everything, But before implementing a thing. So there is only one approach. It's  too difficult to "TDD" all the application, start with little steps. **Good Luck mate!**

Answer (score 0):

A good idea would be to start thinking about this in terms of *your domain* rather than some vague *test*. For example you need to develop **Foo** with functionality of **foo1** and **foo2**.

So you create a test class called `FooTest` with `foo1Test` and `foo2Test`. Initially these tests would fail and you just work to make them pass.

Comment: Because there seems to be two schools of thought it seems. One is to prepare like you would on any project get the business needs, collect user stories, etc. and work from there. The other approach seems to be totally organic. You have nothing but the tests you want your program to do. That second approach blocks me because it is hard to think of the context for the tests - I don't know for example how to name my test class. But, maybe this is as well something that needs to evolve. Maybe I should just give my test class some name, and this will change over time?

Answer (score 0):

What does your system do? You can start there.

Let's assume you're writing a feature that reads a document containing transactions for a given account and generates an aggregate summary of debits and credits.

Let's create a test:

```
public class TransactionSummarizationTest {
    @Test
    public void summarizesAnEmptyDocument() {
        TransactionSummarization summarizer = new TransactionSummarization();
        Summary s = summarizer.summarizeTransactionsIn(new Scanner());
        assertEquals(0.00, s.debits, 0.0);
        assertEquals(0.00, s.credits, 0.0);
    }
```

Since the `TransactionSummarization` and `Summary` classes don't exist yet, you create them now. They would look like so:

TransactionSummarization.java

```
public class TransactionSummarization {
    public Summary summarizeTransactionsIn(Scanner transactionList) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Summary.java

```
public class Summary {
    public double debits;
    public double credits;
}
```

Now that you've taken care of all of the compile errors you may run the test. It will fail with a `NullPointerException` due to your empty implementation of the `summarizeTransactionsIn` method. Return a summary instance from the method and it passes.

```
public Summary summarizeTransactionsIn(Scanner transactionList) {
    return new Summary();
}
```

Run your test again and it passes.

Now that you've got your first test, what's next? I'm thinking that I would want to try the test with a single transaction.

```
@Test
public void summarizesDebit() {
    TransactionSummarization summarizer = new TransactionSummarization();
    Summary s = summarizer.summarizeTransactionsIn(new Scanner("01/01/12,DB,1.00"));
    assertEquals(1.00, s.debits, 0.0);
    assertEquals(0.00, s.credits, 0.0);
}
```

After running the test, we should see it fail because we aren't accumulating the values, simply returning a new `Summary`

```
public Summary summarizeTransactionsIn(Scanner transactionList) {
    String currentLine = transactionList.nextLine();
    txAmount = currentLine.split(",")[2];
    double amount = Double.parseDouble(txAmount);
    return new Summary(amount);
}
```

After fixing the compile error in `Summary` and implementing the constructor your tests should be passing again. What's the next test? What can we learn? Well, I'm curious about that debit/credit thing, so let's do that next.

```
@Test
public void summarizesCredit() {
    TransactionSummarization summarizer = new TransactionSummarization();
    Summary s = summarizer.summarizeTransactionsIn(new Scanner("01/01/12,CR,1.00"));
    assertEquals(0.00, s.debits, 0.0);
    assertEquals(1.00, s.credits, 0.0);
}
```

Run this test, we should see it fail because debits are 1.00, but credits are 0.0. Exactly the opposite of what we wanted, but it's entirely expected because we haven't examined the transaction type in any way. Let's do that now.

```
public Summary summarizeTransactionsIn(Scanner transactionList) {
    double debits = 0.0;
    double credits = 0.0;

    String currentLine = transactionList.nextLine();
    String[] data = currentLine.split(",");
    double amount = Double.parseDouble(data[2]);

    if("DB".equals(data[1]))
        debits += amount;

    if("CR".equals(data[1]))
        credits += amount;

    return new Summary(debits, credits);
}
```

Now all of the tests pass and we can move on to our next test. Now what? I'm thinking that processing only one line in a file won't help us much if we want this project to be successful. How about processing multiple records at the same time? Let's write a test!

```
@Test
public void summarizesDebitsAndCredits() {
    String transactions = "01/01/12,CR,1.75\\n" +
                          "01/02/12,DB,3.00\\n" +
                          "01/02/12,DB,2.50\\n" +
                          "01/02/12,CR,1.25";
    TransactionSummarization summarizer = new TransactionSummarization();
    Summary s = summarizer.summarizeTransactionsIn(new Scanner(transactions));
    assertEquals(5.50, s.debits, 0.0);
    assertEquals(3.00, s.credits, 0.0);
}
```

Now, running all of our tests we see that this one fails in a predictable way. It tells us that our debits are 0.00, and credits are 1.75 since we've only processed the first record.

Let's fix that now. A simple `while` loop and we should be back in business:

```
public Summary summarizeTransactionsIn(Scanner transactionList) {
    double debits = 0.0;
    double credits = 0.0;

    while(transactionList.hasLine()) {
        String currentLine = transactionList.nextLine();
        String[] data = currentLine.split(",");
        double amount = Double.parseDouble(data[2]);

        if("DB".equals(data[1]))
            debits += amount;

        if("CR".equals(data[1]))
            credits += amount;
    }
    return new Summary(debits, credits);
}
```

All the tests pass and I'll leave the rest up to you. Some things to think about are edge cases such as he file containing mixed case, for example "cr" versus "CR", or invalid/missing data, etc.

Also, I realized after I typed all that up that you were referring to C#. Unfortunately I did it in Java and am too lazy to convert it to C#, but I hope this helps anyway. :-)

Thanks!

Brandon